# Exclusive Pattern Matching In Lua

Tags: lua

From this line

```
frame=    2 fps=  0 q=3.0 size=      -0kB time=00:00:13.33 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=92
```

I only want to match the '2' in the frame. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you give any more details about the format? Will there ever be more than one digit? Will the "frame" ever not be first?

Comment: Yes there can be more than one digit. Frame will always be first.

Comment: http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the [Lua pattern](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) string to use:

```
"frame%=[%s]+(%d+)"
```

If you use this in a function like `string.match`, then this will capture the frame number as a string:

```
local framenumber = string.match(testString, "frame%=%s+(%d+)");
```

`framenumber` will either have the captured number (again, as a string. Convert it to a number with `tonumber`) or NIL if it was not found.

Answer (score 2):

If frame is always at the beginning and there is always the same amount of spaces you don't actually need patterns. A simple string.sub will do:

```
local str = "frame=    2 fps= not really important"
local frame = tonumber(str:sub(7,12))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
local data = 'frame=    2 fps=  0 q=3.0 size=      -0kB time=00:00:13.33 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=92'
local _,_, frame = data:find("^frame%=%s+(%d+)")

if frame then
    print("Frame: "..frame)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments, the simple pattern `s:match("%d+")` will work, but `s:match("frame=%s*(%d+)")` is probably more robust in the long run.